# How to add "Resource Description" section to Azure Mobile Services Web API help page

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile Services project with a .NET backend, libraries at 5.2.2 version.

On my project it is important to have complete documentation on the various types, enums and so on.

I am trying to make the Resource Description section appear on the auto-rendered Web API help page, which has been available since Web API 2.1 I think, but for some reason it will not appear in an Azure Mobile Services backend. (see this link for an example of what I want to see http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-4-web-api-help-pages-bson-and-global-error-handling)

Can anyone shed any light on why, or how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported--only the built-in help page is rendered, since you can't use MVC and Mobile Services in the same backend.

The built-in help page is generated by the Mobile Services backend packages, and isn't designed to be extensible. It's mainly there as a simple test harness while you're developing your app.

You might be interested in [Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/07/17/updates-to-the-mobile-apps-server-sdk/), which is the next version of Mobile Services, and does play nicely with MVC. However, Azure Mobile Apps currently in preview, so we don't yet recommend it for production apps.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response. Please could you clarify for me technically what is responsible for making the help page? I am somewhat confused by the fact that Azure Mobile Services is using Web API 2 but the help page is different. I haven't yet had time to take apart Azure Mobile Services and work out what's going on. Azure Mobile Apps is definitely on the radar, but the main obstacle is that there is no Android SDK in the preview version yet.

Comment: Edited with a clarification--the help page is created by the Mobile Services backend packages directly, using something similar to Web API 2 but not the same. What's your use case for the documentation?  I'm guessing you have a lot of custom APIs?

Comment: Yes, exclusively custom APIs. At my employer, there is only native development, carried out by independent programmers. Things like enum values in the DTO and other information needs to be made available to them, to help consume the API, and a good method would be to use the XML comments and auto-generated help page.